# Explain the error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Personlist' with no type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a class which is going to handle an array of objects of another class I've created earlier (which works fine). The problem appears when I try to create an object of my List-class.

This is the header of the list-class:

```
#ifndef personlistH
#define personlistH
#include "Person.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 10

namespace std {

    class PersonList {
private:
    Person persons[SIZE];
    int arrnum;
    string filename;

public:
    Personlist();
    };
}
#endif
```

This is the main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PersonList.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

PersonList personlist;

return 0;   
}
```

The error my compiler is giving me is the following:

> error: "27 \PersonList.h ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Personlist'
>   with no type"

I've searched for answers but as I'm quite new to C++ it's been a bit confusing and I haven't found any fitting yet. It would be great if you could explain this error for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the wrong capitalisation on your constructor declaration. You have `Personlist();` but need `PersonList();`. Because what you have isn't equal to the class name it is considered a function rather than a constructor, and a function needs a return type.

Comment: And you also need to stop putting your own types in namespace std, which is forbidden.

Comment: Correction: Another error exists, sorry. "22 PersonList.h `Person' does not name a type" I guess that might have to do with the original person class?

Comment: I expect so. Can you post the contents of Person.h? Check that Person isn't in a different namespace to PersonList first, which would cause a problem (unless it was in the root namespace).

Answer (score 4):

**Do not** add your own types to the standard namespace(`std`), instead create your own namespace and define your class inside it.

//PersonList.h

```
namespace PersonNamespace 
{
    class PersonList 
    {
        //members here
    };
}
```

//Main.cpp

```
using namespace PersonNamespace;
```

The actual error is that you made a typo in `Personlist` instead of `PersonList`

Comment: So by that you mean I should do something similar to this: namespace x { class bla bla }.... then using namespace x; ?

Comment: I've changed it to another namespace, as you've shown but the error still exists. :/

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes, I noticed that a bit later,The first thing i Noticed is the violation of what Standard states regarding extensding `std` namespace.

Comment: Correction: Another error exists, sorry. "22 PersonList.h `Person' does not name a type" I guess that might have to do with the original person class?

Comment: @cubsink: Notice the capital `L` in `PersonList()` You have mistyped it as small letter `l` as `Personlist()`, change that and it will work.

Comment: @Als: I did change that, and that gave me the error "Person does not name a type"

Comment: @cubsink: Show the contents of "Person.h" file.

Comment: @cubsink: You already accepted an answer,So what was the problem regarding `Person`, care to share?

Comment: http://pastie.org/2773073 <- I know I am doing something forbidden there but I would rather not change it if it's possible since then I probably have to change it in at least 3 files more. But I will certainly keep the namespace thing in mind in the future.

I hope there is a workaround.

Comment: And sorry Als, my internet connection went down. That person solved the original problem first, so I thought I should give him/her some credit :)

Comment: @cubsink: you need to move `Person` out of the `std` namespace too. (Or if you really want to leave it there, even though that's forbidden, you'll need to refer to it as `std::Person` in other namespaces).

Comment: @Mike: Thanks a bunch. I will leave it there this time even though it's forbidden (may the gods punish me). I will never do it again tho.

Comment: @cubsink - Three files is not a lot to change in order to fix the namespace issue. Plus it's better that you change it now rather than let it become a bad habit.

Comment: @cubsink: No worries.I was just curious about the problem that is why, And Yes always accept the answer that helps you in best way for solving your problem. All the Best :)

Comment: @cubsink: IMHO if it is mere 3 files(Yes, 3 is actually mere in context that you would work with projects with 1000's of files in future),You should consider removing your type defined in `std` namespace.It is always good to follow good(rather correct) practices.Anyhow,You know that is incorrect and if you still want to go ahead with it,go ahead but do remember it in future.

Comment: Well I agree with all of you, but this is actually an old lab from a summer course. And I just need to learn some new stuff that I missed out in the summer (worked too much so I didn't have much time then). I guarantee you that I will learn from my mistake and never do it again.

Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @cubsink: No worries and All the Best :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you got the capitalisation wrong when you declared the constructor; it should be `PersonList()` not `Personlist()`.

Also, you should never declare your own classes in the `std` namespace; that's reserved for the standard library. You shoud make up your own namespace name, and put your things in that.